# How can I control the name of generic WCF return types?

Tags: wcf, web-services, generics

I've got a WCF Web Service method whose prototype is:

```
[OperationContract]
Response<List<Customer>> GetCustomers();
```

When I add the service reference to a client, Visual Studio (2005) creates a type called "ResponseOfArrayOfCustomerrleXg3IC" that is a wrapper for "Response<List<Customer>>".  Is there any way I can control the wrapper name?  ResponseOfArrayOfCustomerrleXg3IC doesn't sound very appealing...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define your own name in the `DataContract` attribute like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ResponseOf{0}")]
public class Response<T>
```

Note that in your example the `{0}` will be replaced and your proxy reference type will be `ResponseOfArrayOfCustomer`.

More info here: [WCF: Serialization and Generics](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
[OperationContract]
[return: MessageParameter(Name="YOURNAME")]
Response<List<Customer>> GetCustomers();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The OperationContractAttribute takes a parameter called Name. You could specify it like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "NameGoesHere")]
Response<List<Customer>> GetCustomers();
```

Comment: I don't want to specify the name of the operation, I want to specify the name of the DataContract.  The problem is the DataContract I'm using is generic.