# How do I change the outer object's name using WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, webhttp

I'm using a WCF .svc class like so:

```
[DataContract] public class FunInfo { ... }
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

public FunInfo SetInformation(int a, int b) { ... }
```

When I get my JSON back, it looks like this:

```
{"SetInformationResult":{ ... } }
```

My question is: Where did SetInformationResult come from, and can I control it's name without renaming my class?  To "d", for instance, to mimic what the ScriptService does?

EDIT: For posterity, relevant links I've found since: [How can I control the name of generic WCF return types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172265/how-can-i-control-the-name-of-generic-wcf-return-types)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The name came from your operation name with "Result" appended to it. And you can rename it by using the `[MessageParameter]` attribute on the return of the method:

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(...)]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "d")]
public FunInfo SetInformation(int a, int b) { ... }
```

Comment: Wow I searched high and low for that, and couldn't find it documented anywhere.  The ASP.NET WCF/ASMX system could be MSDN's worst-documented API anywhere... thanks!

Comment: this was driving me crazy.