# wcf request wrapper name

Tags: .net, wcf

Is there any way to change the wrapper used for a WCF request that uses `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` or `WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` instead of using the operation name?

So for the following:

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
       UriTemplate = "foo")]
bool PutSomeValue(string id, string bar);
```

instead of the request being:

```
<PutSomeValue>
    <id>1234</id>
    <bar>myValue</bar>
</PutSomeValue>
```

I want it to be:

```
<MyNewWrapperName>
    <id>1234</id>
    <bar>myValue</bar>
</MyNewWrapperName>
```

I know it's possible with the response and we can change individual parameters on the request but I can't find any information about changing the request wrapper.

EDIT: The reason I want to do this is to change the wrapper to something generic like "Parameters" or "Request" and preferrably have the same wrapper for each of my operations.  I think this would be cleaner and more user friendly than requiring the client to worry about each request's wrapper, plus it would reveal less metadata.

Comment: Won't it be more confusing than helpful if you have the same wrapper for every operation?

Answer (score 1):

similar question here;
[How can I control the name of generic WCF return types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172265/how-can-i-control-the-name-of-generic-wcf-return-types)

and the answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/172370/929902

```
[OperationContract]
[return: MessageParameter(Name="YOURNAME")]
Response<List<Customer>> GetCustomers();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[OperationContract(Name = "MyNewWrapperName")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
       UriTemplate = "foo")]
bool PutSomeValue(string id, string bar);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that, but it limits me to providing a unique wrapper for each operation.  This would defeat one of the reasons I want to do this (see my edit above).